# Bold and uncentered table caption from longtables in memoir

Tags: memoir, longtable

I'm using the longtable package for a document of the memoir class and I adjusted the Figure captions to be bold (e.g. "**Figure 1:**"). Now, I tried to achieve the same for the longtable caption but don't get it right, i.e. I want to have the table name in bold as well (like "**Table 1:**"). Since I'm using memoir I'd like to avoid including `\usepackage{caption}`. At the same time, longtable requires the `\caption{}` command to be the first command within the environment, that's why I can not simply define a new caption command via `\newcommand` with the memoir specific parameters for captions.

I guess I have to tweek the longtable command `\LT@makecaption` directly but my LaTeX/Tex skills are simply too little to do so. Does anybody know how to proceed?

Once the caption is bold I guess this shows me how I can also get it not centered anymore ...

Here is a MWE that outputs a tiny longtable with the caption name in normal font and centered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
  \begin{longtable}{rr}
    \caption{A simple longtable} \\
    \hline
    First col & Second col \\ \hline 
    \endfirsthead

    \multicolumn{2}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    First col & Second col \\
    \hline
    \endhead

    \hline \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot

    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\

  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a  *full* minimal example, with the preamble you have.

Comment: i'm not sure what you like to achive ... see if `\captionstyle[\raggedright]{\centerlastline}` in preamble gives what you looking for.

Comment: @Bernard sorry for that! The example should be complete now.

Comment: @Zarko sorry for the inaccuracy. I edited my post to make it clearer. I want to have the name of the table, i.e. "**Table 1:**" in bold. Moreover, in default setting the longtable is centered, so the caption is centered as well. For short captions, this looks odd because the caption does not start left-justified as all other captions.

Comment: @Kolja, see my answer below. my suggestion works, however, you also need to adjust `\LTcapwidth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i guess that you looking for something like this:

[image]

(red lines show page layout), mwe, which generate this image, is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\captionstyle[\raggedright]{\centerlastline}    % <--- added
\captionnamefont{\bfseries}                     % <--- added
\usepackage{longtable}
\setlength\LTcapwidth{\linewidth}               % <--- added

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
  \begin{longtable}{rr}
    \caption{A simple longtable} \\
    \hline
    First col & Second col \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{2}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    First col & Second col \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    1 & 2 \\
  \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

changes in comparison to your mwe are indicated by `% <--- added`.

note: if you like to have caption of table on the next page positioned on the same way, you need to replace

```
   \multicolumn{2}{c}%
    {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
```

with

```
    \caption{A simple longtable \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
```

Comment: Awesome! I did not expect it to be that easy but that is even better. That is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Kolja, than you can accept answer (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer) :-)